# When installing the Firebase Pod, I did not get FirebaseDatabase module?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to read and write data to a Firebase database with my app. However, when I installed the pod, it only installed Firebase, FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseCore, and FirebaseInstanceID.

Is there anyway to get this module another way? Also, if it might have missed any other modules, can you tell me how to get those too? Thanks.

this is what I get when I do pod install with 'Firebase/Database'

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Firebase/DataBase` required by `Podfile`
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency:
>   `Firebase/DataBase`.
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
>   `pod repo update`.  * mistyped the name or version.  * not added the
>   source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
>
> Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod
>   install` by default.

Comment: What does your podfile looks like? If it miss pod 'Firebase/Database' you have to add it and then run pod install. Also tell me if this were the issue and I'll add answer that you can accept.

Comment: @i6x86 please see above with the error I got for that.

Comment: @i6x86 I actually just tried something else. I looked for a pod and it is just simply pod 'FirebaseDatabase'. Feel free to post as answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If you did something different than my suggestion and it worked, you are the one that should post the answer.

Comment: Try building your project with `cmd+B` then try to import the firebase modules

Comment: @i6x86 I can post as an answer, I was giving you the option though because I did the same thing you told me to do but without the /

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe ok just posted an answer! I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the database SDK by adding this line in your podfile:

pod 'FirebaseDatabase'